# getting different JSON response on iPhone, Android and on browser

Tags: iphone, json, asihttprequest

I am getting the json data over the http and parsing it.
The web service url is http://www.thementalelf.net/page/1/?json=get_recent_posts
I am using ASIHttp asynchronous request for getting the data, the code is as below for iPhone.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.thementalelf.net/page/1/?json=get_recent_posts";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

for parsing I am using SBJson

```
 NSString *responseString = [request responseString];            
 SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];            
 NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:NULL];
```

In Android I am using HttpClient and JSONObject for parsing it, the code is as below

```
 String Url = "http://www.thementalelf.net/page/1/?json=get_recent_posts";
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet request = new HttpGet(Url);
 response = client.execute(request);

 String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(responseBody);
```

the response string differs in iPhone and android. the response in iPhone clips out the thumbnail tag which is giving me the url for image. does anyone come across such problem or know what the problem is?

Comment: Having been a member of Stack Overflow for 10 months, you should have found a couple of minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) including the "how to ask questions" section. There are so many possible answers to what you have put that it's difficult to know where to begin.

Comment: thanks for letting me know Nick, if I would have know the specificity of the problem I wouldn't have asked the question. I tried searching on stack but didn't found anyone with same problem. Its blowing my head as I have no Idea why iPhone not giving me what every other does.

Comment: Other search engines are available. How are we supposed to be able to help you? The problem could be in your code that you have for requesting and retrieving the data (but we don't know because you haven't posted it). The problem could be in the code you are using for decoding the returned data (but we don't know because you haven't posted it). The problem could be that your server is returning different data depending on the client requesting it (but we don't know if you have tried that because you haven't said). Like I said - there are lots of possibilities.

Comment: I had searched on other search engines as well, but didn't got anything. I have edited the question with code for iPhone and android. I have no idea about server side, apart from that they are using some plugins for wordpress for the web services which gets data from site and converts it into xml and send it. can you please help if you got any problem with code or something.